# rewrite rule for WordPress 3.3 permalinks is not working

Tags: regex, apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite

Every since an upgrade to WordPress 3.3 URLs are not redirecting as they should.
Changed: **domain.com/2010/10/postname/** to: **domain.com/postname/**

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the leading slash and not using $3

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.+)$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a script here you can use to generate .htaccess rules if you want to change permalinks to the /%postname%/ structure.

http://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/

My permalinks were exactly the same as yours, I used this tool to change them and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

The last rule will never get applied if the previous rule matches. Assuming that the **http://domain.com/2010/10/postname/** request doesn't match a file or directory, the `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` is going to rewrite the URI to `/index.php` thus it'll never get to your rule. Try moving your rule up to the top, just below `RewriteBase /`, and duplicate the !-f/!-d conditions, so that it looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /

# for 301 redirect    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

# the rest of the rules
RewriteRule ^atom.xml$ feed/ [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ feed/ [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rss2.xml$ feed/ [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedValidator [NC]
RewriteRule ^feed/?([_0-9a-z-]+)?/?$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/handle [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Also, if this is in an .htaccess file, you need to remove the leading slash in the rule match so that it looks like this: `^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$`

Comment: Note, the redirection is not working at all in IE, I believe Firefox may of somehow cached the redirect from when it was working.